# runtime error type mismatch for array vlookup

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, vlookup

I have encounter

> runtime error 13 type mismatch

while running below code. Basically I would like to use values in column 31 to vlookup in another sheet to return searched value in column 32, searched date in column 33.

Please kindly help me out.

```
Sub vlookupFU()

'vlookupfollowup material & Eff-out date
Dim wkbNPI As Workbook
Dim wksPT As Worksheet
Dim wksFU As Worksheet

Set wkbNPI = ActiveWorkbook
Set wksPT = wkbNPI.Sheets("Packaging tracking")
Set wksFU = wkbNPI.Sheets("FollowUpMaterial")

Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
Dim lrw2 As Long
    lrw2 = wksPT.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

Dim PTarray As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long

PTarray = wksPT.Range("A7:AG" & lrw2)

Dim Oldcode As String
Dim FUM As String           'Follow up material code
Dim FUMD As String            'Follow up material date

For i = 1 To lrw2
Oldcode = PTarray(i, 31)

    If Oldcode <> 0 Then 'where I have error type mismatch

    FUM = wf.vlookup(PTarray(i, 31), wksFU.Range("B:R"), 13, False)               'vlookup follow up material
    FUMD = wf.vlookup(PTarray(i, 31), wksFU.Range("B:R"), 17, False)              'vlookup follow up material effective out date
    FUM = PTarray(i, 32)
    FUMD = PTarray(i, 33)

    End If


Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `vlookup()` returns a value and not an object. Therefore it has no `.Value` or `.Text` property. Remove that. • And remove `On Error Resume Next` this line is useless in this case. It is recommended never to use `On Error Resume Next` without proper error handling at all.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ,thanks I have changed as suggest, but type mismatch error still remains

Comment: In which line does this error occur then?

Comment: In this line below, as in this column there is also a lot of blank cell, I would like to skip those blank cells. If Oldcode <> 0 Then

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will work as you expect it to, to skip blank cells you could do it like:

`If Oldcode <> "" Then`

Please see below for your amended code, I've also removed the `lrw2` as not being used in the code, another point to consider is that you don't place the returned value from the Vlookup anywhere apart from a variable, so this will not add the values into your excel sheet? Not sure if this is something you are working on or not...:

```
Sub vlookupFU()
'vlookupfollowup material & Eff-out date
Dim wkbNPI As Workbook: Set wkbNPI = ThisWorkbook
Dim wksPT As Worksheet: Set wksPT = wkbNPI.Sheets("Packaging tracking")
Dim wksFU As Worksheet: Set wksFU = wkbNPI.Sheets("FollowUpMaterial")
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction: Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
Dim lrw2 As Long, i As Long ', j As Long
Dim PTarray As Variant
Dim Oldcode As String, FUM As String, FUMD As String

'lrw2 = wksPT.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'not used so no need for this line
PTarray = wksPT.Range("A7:AG" & lrw2)

For i = 1 To wksPT.Range("A7:AG" & lrw2).Rows.Count
    Oldcode = PTarray(i, 31)

    If Oldcode <> "" Then
        FUM = wf.VLookup(PTarray(i, 31), wksFU.Range("B:R"), 13, False)               'vlookup follow up material
        FUMD = wf.VLookup(PTarray(i, 31), wksFU.Range("B:R"), 17, False)              'vlookup follow up material effective out date
        'FUM = PTarray(i, 32) 'you get the value above and then you overwrite it here??
        'FUMD = PTarray(i, 33) 'you get the value above and then you overwrite it here??
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Then I have a different error 9- subscript out of rang in line  `    Oldcode = PTarray(i, 31)  `

Comment: @loriiii updated my answer, you shouldn't get an error now, I've changed the For Loop from lrw2 to the number of rows in the range you are looping through.